# Highlighting or Bolding the Borders of a kml Polygon

Tags: kml, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

Hey after loading a kml file to google earth I was trying to have when a user clicks a certain polygon from the kml, to have that polygon highlighted.

So far I can record the click event, get the event type (KmlPlacemark) and grab its kml markup.
I tried doing something similar to this [example](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/kml#getting_kml) where they add a placemark to the getFeatures of the kmlObject but both target and type don't seem to have 'getFeatures'. After looking around the documentation I think I might either want setOutline from Kml Polystyle class  or setWidth() from KmlLineStyle class but am not sure. Also when I try something like  target.setOutline(true); it doesn't work.

Can anyone tell me if I'm on the right track, hints to what I'm doing wrong, and if there's a better way to do this?

```
function recordEvent(event) {
            var target = event.getTarget();
            var type = target.getType();


            if(type == "KmlPolygon") {
                alert("KMLPolygon ");
            }else if(type == "KmlPlacemark") {
                // // get the data you want from the target.
                var description = target.getDescription();
                var balloon = target.getBalloonHtml();
                var outputKml = target.getKml();

                if ('getFeatures' in event) {
                    console.log("test");
                    event.getFeatures().appendChild(placemark);
                }

                console.log("hello?")
                // target.setOutline(true);
                console.log(outputKml);
            }
        };

      google.earth.addEventListener(ge.getGlobe(), 'click', recordEvent);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I find the best way to do what you are asking is to:

1. Detect click events like you currently do
2. If clicked, create a new Style, then assign it to the target

   ```
   var newStyle = ge.createStyle('');
   // Assign your Style's attributes such as LabelStyle and IconStyle
   // eg to set the scale of your label
   newStyle.getLabelStyle().setScale(2.5);
   // Set the Style
   target.setStyleSelector(newStyle);
   ```

Edit to add in this link of a Google example showing it more in depth
https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#styling_placemarks_using_style_maps